# Digits.sharedInstance() crashing on devices

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits, fabric-digits

I integrated Digits by Fabric a while ago in my iOS project to authenticate users by phone numbers and it was all working fine until recently when my app started crashing due to following line of code where we initialize Digits in our project:

```
Digits.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "myConsumerKey", consumerSecret: "myConsumerSecret")
```

Giving following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]:
>   nil string parameter'

I have tried all options but couldn't find the solution any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deleted Digits from my pods and reinstalled it, it started working with warning that I have to upgrade to new phone authentication service by Firebase as Digits has been acquired by Google.